# Want to find user using user_id in node js using mongoose

Tags: node.js

want to find user using user_id in node js using mongoose using nodejs .on submiting it shows user not exist

```
 Route.get("/getdata",(req,res)=>{
                const { firstname,lastname,username}=req.body;
                const user = User.findOne({firstname,lastname,username});
                if(user===user._id){
                    res.status(200).json(user);
                    console.log(user);
                }
                else{
                    res.status(401).json("user not registered");
                    console.log("user is not registered");
                }
            });
```

**index.ejs**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>Hello world</p>
        <h1>Welcome to page </h1>
        <form action="/register/getdata" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="enter user id">
        <button type="submit">click</button>
    </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know about asynchronous, Promise, callback, async await to fix it.

```
         Route.get("/getdata",async (req,res)=>{
            const { firstname,lastname,username}=req.body;
            const user = await User.findOne({firstname,lastname,username});
            if(user===user._id){
                res.status(200).json(user);
                console.log(user);
            }
            else{
                res.status(401).json("user not registered");
                console.log("user is not registered");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Always wrap your code inside try catch block when using async function. Otherwise your application will crash if some error occurs.

Comment: No need to check ```user===user.id``` if ```findOne()``` returns some value then already user exists otherwise do not exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch data by two ways.

**callback method**

```
User.findOne(filter, (err, doc){
  if(err) {
    //handle error and return.
  }
  //proceed with result.
});
```

**Using built in promise**

```
User.findOne(filter)
.then(result=>{
//proceed with result.
})
.catch(err=>{
//handle error
})
```

**Or Async/Await**

for using Await you have to make your function async.

```
Router.get('/getdata', async(req, res, next){
  try{
    const user = await User.findOne(filter);
    //proceed with result.
  }
  catch(err){
    //handle error
  }
})


----------
```

Your code need some modification so I'm posting with updated code.

```
Route.get("/getdata", async(req,res)=>{
  try{
    const {firstname, lastname, username} = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({firstname, lastname, username});
    if(user){
      res.status(200).json(user);
      console.log(user);
    }else{
      res.status(401).json("user not registered");
      console.log("user is not registered");
    }
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    //handle error
  }
});
```

You don't need to explicitly verify `user===user.id` (I don't know for what purpose you are using as it is wrong object cannot be equal to its property), since you are using `findOne()` so it will give result only if match is found else null.